# Infinite tic tac toe complexity?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, game-theory

So I was wondering in tic tac toe in infinite dimensions where instead of a 2D grid I play on an infinite dimensional hypercube. I've come to the conclusion the words optimal strategy does not make sense (?) How? Imagine I score a win using an optimal strategy (assuming it exists). Then using the projection operator I can project part of the game on a 2 dimensional grid and work backwards, then add a cross product of another 2d grid and so on ...

What I mean by optimal strategy is one cannot even make statements like corners are the optimal positions. Consider the counterexample in the simplest 2d case (normal tic-tac-toe with chess notation).

X: B1
O: A3
X: C3

Now O is forced to move A1 (anything else loses) ... So now one may add forced moves + corners are a good thing strategically ... My question is how does one prove or disprove an optimal strategy exists/does not exist? How does one define complexity of the optimal strategy? (Assuming that's a sensible question)

Comment: If an optimal strategy does exist then what makes this game special that one can clearly define it?

Comment: How many in a row do you need to win?

Comment: I'm tempted to say more the merrier but even in the case of one I'd like to see this play out ...

Comment: @fleablood I'm sorry I thought you said how many rows do you need to win. 3 in a row should be enough.

Comment: Have you looked into finite-dimensional tic-tac-toe strategies?According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/909808/279914) the first player has a winning strategy on a $3^n$ board if $n\ge 3$. You could try applying the same strategy to the $3^\omega$ game.

Comment: Well, a winning strategy for 3 exists for 3 in a row if the dimensions are two or  more and the size of a board is infinite (or, I think 4 or more).  The first player can always win.  Move 1: make a mark.  Player B does any thing.  Move 2. Make a mark adjecent to the original mark in such a way that you have two in a row unblocked on either end. (If you had $n$ dimensions there are $3^n-1$ adjecent neighbors. Player Bs mark can cut of $2$ of them but there are still $3^n-3$ choices). Player B can only block at most one.  Move 3: Put a mark in an open end and get three in a row.